# play a video right away

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-videoview

I am trying to use VideoView to play a streaming video and what seems to happen is that it has to download the entire video before it will play even the first second.  obviously, I would like it to start playing the video as soon as possible.  is there something I can do with VideoView to make this work, or is this something that's controlled on the site hosting the video URL?

Comment: not sure what that comment is about.

Comment: I guess the VideoView requires a minimum buffer to be loaded before starting playing. The buffer size may depend on the device or the android version.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the file you have uploaded (or linked to) is not streamable and it will have to play it locally.

Can you check if it still happens with other video's ?

Comment: do you have an example video url?  if I used the phone's camera to record the video, should it be in a streamable format?